# Replacing text jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code to search for text and replace it. I have the divs inside of a datalist. This jquery will only edit the first two of the items on the list. How could I have it search all of the list and/or entire page for this text and replace it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var elem = $("#details").html(); // fetch the HTML from the #foo ID
            var elem2 = $("#details2").html();
            var bath = "Bathroom"; // text to replace 
            var bedroom = "Bedroom"; // text to replace
            var replaceBath = "Bath"; // text to replace with
            var replaceBed = "Bed"; // text to replace with
            elem = elem.replace(bath, replaceBath); // replace & update string
            elem = elem.replace(bedroom, replaceBed); // replace & update string
            elem2=elem2.replace(bath,replaceBath);
            elem2=elem2.replace(bedroom,replaceBed);
            $("#details").html(elem); // apply updated string to #foo
            $("#details2").html(elem2);
            alert(elem2);


        });
    </script>
```

I have these 2 divs inside of a datalist.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="details" id="details1"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Bedrooms", "{0:n0}") %>  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Bathrooms", "{0:n1}") %> Single Family Home</div>
                  </div>

 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="details" id="details2"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Bedrooms", "{0:n0}") %>  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Bathrooms", "{0:n1}") %> Single Family Home</div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using each:

```
$(function () {

    var bath = "Bathroom"; // text to replace 
    var bedroom = "Bedroom"; // text to replace
    var replaceBath = "Bath"; // text to replace with
    var replaceBed = "Bed"; // text to replace with
    $(".details").each(function(){
        var elem = $(this).html().replace(bath, replaceBath).replace(bedroom,replaceBed);
        $(this).html(elem);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [Contains() selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) should be able to help identify any element on the page that contains the search string. By using the `*` selector, we tell jQuery to look at every tag in the DOM.

```
var matches = $( "*:contains(" + stringToLookFor + ")" );
```